# Why does barista/coffeescript not tell you what is wrong when you have an error?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-construction, coffeescript

I am trying out coffeescript with barista, and I am not having a good time with it.

For some reason, whenever I make a change to a .coffee file, barista complains that there is a compile error except for the most trivial of cases (like a simple call to 'alert').

When I get these error messages, it doesn't actually tell me what's wrong - it just says that there is a 'V8: JSError'. There are no line numbers. Nothing.

To fix these errors, I CTRL-C the Rails server and restart it... and all is well... but making any change at all to the .coffee file just causes Barista to throw yet another compiler error - and the process repeats. Even if I add correct Coffeescript code, it still throws a compiler error. I have no idea why.

How can anyone program like this? I need good feedback or I am totally lost. Most of the time, the .coffee file contains no error because it compiles after I restart the server.

I also prefer fast feedback, or I get impatient. One of the attractions to developing with rails is that everything is pretty immediate. This coffeescript thing though has to be as bad as working in Java.

As much as I hate javascript, at least the feedback is more responsive and I don't have to restart the server.

Did I just set this up wrong? Is this really what it's like to code in coffeescript? If it is... then why is this being forced on everyone in rails 3.1?

I'm just not having a good day today. I'm sorry if this comes off as bad. I've been spending hours with coffeescript and I honestly am not getting very far. Programming without detailed error messages and being forced to restart the server to see my changes take effect reminds me of Java... and that's why I stopped using it in the first place.

:(

Comment: Did someone seriously vote my post down from 2 to 1 and vote to close it? This is a legitimate question and 2 others thought so as well.

Comment: Probably because you have too much subjective description. Whether you are having a good time, whether you can be patient, whether you hate something: these are not programming question. We are not reading your personal weblog.

Comment: That's 1 paragraph in the whole post.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011296/barista-is-saying-theres-compile-errors-whenever-i-make-changes-have-to-resta

Comment: It's a shame. I think coffeescript is a neat experiment, but the extra layer of abstraction/complexity, the poor tooling and poor integration with rails probably adds to the fact that it's not ready for prime time yet. As much as I hate javascript, I would have been more productive in it today. I'm sure it's not coffeescript's fault... it could just be barista's fault. I don't know. It doesn't seem like anyone else knows either. I have to face the reality that I need to get work done.

Comment: write a blog instead, question has no question in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that when Barista encounters a compile-time error in your CoffeeScript code, it takes that error message and uses it as the JS output. Since that error message is invalid JS, you get a vague error from your browser. If you can think of a better way to do this, you should [raise an issue](https://github.com/sutto/barista/issues) to suggest it.

For now, what you should do is either

1. View the source of the page, get the address of the JS file, and open it up directly in your browser, or
2. Use your text editor's “Build” feature (e.g. Cmd+B in TextMate) to show the compiled output, or compilation errors, of the responsible CoffeeScript file, or
3. Use the [barista_growl](https://github.com/Burgestrand/barista_growl) plugin so that you get a Growl notification when a compilation error occurs.

None of the above is ideal, but browser support for CoffeeScript debugging is coming...

Comment: I'm not on a mac, just ubuntu, so some of those options won't be available me thinks. Thanks for the response though. At least you've answered the question honestly and gave me the info I needed. It's better than me thinking I did something incorrectly. I think I will wait to use coffeescript until my next project. I am learning backbone.js as well, and I guess learning 1 major thing is enough right now without dealing with extra steps and the like. I hope Rails 3.1 doesn't ship with this problem still in place. That would probably make a lot of people angry.

Comment: I think the idea case for coffeescript integration with rails is to show compilation errors in coffeescript to be exactly like interpreter errors for erb - you know, have it be exactly the same workflow. Once they can get it to that point, I will be sold on it.

Comment: Yeah, that approach could be an improvement. (Rails 3.1 isn't doing that either, yet.)

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I got the chance to talk with some of the core Rails folks at RailsConf today, and it sounds like they will be providing feedback for CoffeeScript errors in much the way that they do for ERB errors when Rails 3.1 is released. :)

Comment: Great news! I wish rails 3.1 was out today so I could use it ;) Oh well.